# Scrape webpage vs NodeJS

Tags: node.js

trying to scrape hotel names from this web page:
http://www.booking.com/searchresults.ru.html?dcid=1&flash_deals=1

This is my code:

```
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    urls = [];

request('http://www.booking.com/searchresults.ru.html?dcid=1&flash_deals=1', function(err, res, body) {
    if(!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('a.hotelname base', '#dealsfound_inner').each(function(){
            var url = this.text();
            urls.push(url);
        });

        console.log(urls);
    }
});
```

Console returns empty array. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL was moved. Look at your http headers, e.g. using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

```
> curl -i "http://www.booking.com/searchresults.ru.html?dcid=1&flash_deals=1"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 03 Feb 2014 18:53:38 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.booking.com/searchresults.ru.html
X-Recruiting: Like HTTP headers? Come write ours: booking.com/jobs
```

Maybe the site has some type of protection system to prevent things like you are doing.

Comment: Looks like booking.com uses cookies for this page. Is there way to use cookies when you trying to scrap some page?

Comment: Sure. They are part of the http header when sent by the server.

Comment: Try adding a User-Agent to your http-header. Maybe they are looking for real browsers.